# is there any different in Connection string between SQL server Authentication and Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008

is there any different in Connection string

between SQL server Authentication and  Windows Authentication

if yes, can i get a sample connection string for this ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows authentication

> connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

SQL server Authentication

> ConnectionString="Server=MyServer;
>   Database=pubs; User Id=MyUser;
>   password= P@ssw0rd"